Pinescript request.securities not returning consistent data, pinescript v5
I requested data from a higher timeframe "selectedTimeframe" but the float array returned is completly incosistent with what i have on the actual higher timeframe
note: the chart below is the higher timeframe(4h), and the one above is the lower timeframe(1h)

here is the code :
float ph = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, selectedTimeframe, ta.pivothigh(src1, prd, prd)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0],barmerge.gaps_on)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
float pl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, selectedTimeframe, ta.pivotlow(src2, prd, prd)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0],barmerge.gaps_on)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

note: the main issue is that it returns a different price for the 4h and a different on 1h where the 4h price is being requested
I have tried manually unputting the timeframe string, but that seems not to be the issue, i also created a temporary request for just the close price on the higher time frame, but that also yielded the same result, the higher was inconsistent with whats displayed on the lower timeframe

Please don't publish your code as an image

Maybe the error must be in the offset

the issue is not what is plotted, the issue is that it returns a different price for the 4h and a different on 1h

If you need a Pivot MTF, this example can help you: https://www.tradingview.com/v/w2cENzrs/

I am watching this issue of yours because I discovered the same problem yesterday. I'm getting different lows and high values for the same timeperiod depending on the timeframe. For example INDEX:BTCUSD shows different Low values on the 5min vs Day timeperiods for April 2nd and April 3rd. On the Daily April 2nd is the Low, on 5min Apr 3rd is the low. Different values.

thanks to @Gu5tavo71 i was able to get it working with the template from - tradingview.com/v/w2cENzrs
